# UWP CMake Project XamlCompiler error WMC1002

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, cmake, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to migrate a Universal Windows Platform application to CMake and I'm receiving the following error when building:

```
\src\windows-uwp\App.xaml : XamlCompiler error WMC1002: x:Class type 'langdetect.App' is not found in 'langdetect'
```

I did end up changing the name of the namespace to match the CMake project name during the migration but I'm almost sure I've updated all references. All of the C/C++ code compiles just fine. I'm using CMake 3.5.2 and Visual Studio Community 2015.

This is App.xaml:

```
<Application
x:Class="langdetect.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:langdetect"
RequestedTheme="Light">

</Application>
```

App.xaml.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "App.g.h"

namespace langdetect
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
ref class App sealed
{
protected:
    virtual void OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e) override;

internal:
    App();

private:
    void OnSuspending(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingEventArgs^ e);
    void OnNavigationFailed(Platform::Object ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationFailedEventArgs ^e);
};
}
```

This is the UWP specific code in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include_directories(./include/windows-uwp)
ADD_MSVC_PRECOMPILED_HEADER("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/windows-uwp/pch.h" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/windows-uwp/pch.cpp" SRC_FILES)
set (HEADER_FILES include/gui.h include/langdetect.h include/windows-uwp/App.xaml.h 
    include/windows-uwp/MainPage.xaml.h include/windows-uwp/langdetect-uap.h
    include/windows-uwp/str-utils.h)

set (SRC_FILES src/windows-uwp/App.xaml.cpp src/langdetect.c src/gui.c src/windows-uwp/MainPage.xaml.cpp 
    src/windows-uwp/langdetect-uap.cpp src/windows-uwp/str-utils.cpp
    src/windows-uwp/App.xaml
    src/windows-uwp/MainPage.xaml)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/ZW /EHsc")
```

Comment: I'd look at some more verbose logs and make sure your app.xaml.cpp/h is compiled before the XAML compiler gets to app.xaml.

Answer (score 6):

This can be fixed in two ways:

1. In Visual Studio, on the Properties of App.xaml, General, set `Item Type` to `XAML Application Definition` [Visual Studio XAML Properties Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY4jy.png)
2. In your `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following line: `set_source_files_properties(App.xaml PROPERTIES VS_XAML_TYPE ApplicationDefinition)`

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/prop_sf/VS_XAML_TYPE.html for an explanation about this CMake property.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is having this problem, I will post how I fixed it.

CMake did not generate the Visual Studio project files correctly for my application. To fix the original error, I needed to change a few lines in the generated Visual Studio project file (.vcxproj)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="App.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainPage.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```

App.xaml needs to be included under an ApplicationDefinition tag or you will receive error WMC1002.

I changed the above code to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MainPage.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```

This fixed error WMC1002, however, I received 3 more errors.

```
Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(66): error C2039: 'MainPage': is not a member of 'langdetect' [build\langdetect.vcxproj]
  include\windows-uwp\App.xaml.h(10): note: see declaration of 'langdetect'
Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(66): error C2065: 'MainPage': undeclared identifier [build\langdetect.vcxproj]
Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(82): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'Platform::Object ^(__cdecl *)(void)' [build\langdetect.vcxproj]
  Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(82): note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

It took me a long time to figure out what was causing this. Yet again, it is caused by another issue with the generated project file.

```
<ClInclude Include="App.xaml.h" />
<ClInclude Include="MainPage.xaml.h" />
```

The ClInclude tags for XAML pages require a child DependentUpon tag to function correctly it seems. I changed the above code to the following and it fixed my issue.

```
<ClInclude Include="App.xaml.h">
    <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
</ClInclude>
<ClInclude Include="MainPage.xaml.h">
    <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</ClInclude>
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or just an issue with my CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your default namespace at the project level.